# How do you encrypt data before storing it?

Tags: xubuntu, encryption, security, data-recovery

If data can always be recovered no mater how you erase it (correct me if I'm wrong), is it possible to encrypt the data **before** saving it so that an unencrypted part of it is never stored? Let's say a text file.

[Xubuntu 20.04 LTS | live USB]

Comment: To encrypt data **before** saving it, you must use programs that have that capacity, so use text editors that can do it.  You can also encrypt files for normal programs (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GnuPrivacyGuardHowto maybe useful)   Myself I'd just rely on full-disk encryption, which means once you shutdown your system, all data is encrypted (encryption is bypassed when you're logged in)  Yes *they* can in theory decrypt anything, but if it takes *months* of hi-powered processing to achieve it; it maybe only matters if you're hiding from govt as the risk to normal users is negligible

Comment: A ten pound sledge hammer will encrypt all data on drive so it can't be recovered by NSA.  Not putting data on drive also prevents recovery.  Only put data on drive you don't care about or encrypt the drive as giuverc suggests.

Answer (score 0):

What are your goals in encrypting your data?

The Ubuntu installer offers an option to encrypt your Ubuntu installation, using a technique known as "full disk encryption". When you boot your computer, you'll need to enter a passphrase that is used to decrypt the key that is used to encrypt your filesystem. If someone steals your computer, or your drive, and it is powered off, they'll need the passphrase before they can access your data.

If your concern is what other people on the system can see while it's running, then full disk encryption may not help much: but using file system permissions correctly can help keep non-root users from your files. Encrypting your files with gpg or other tools may help, in case your permissions settings aren't correct. However, working with gpg or other tools for this case can be a bit exhausting: it certainly isn't as easy as one passphrase at each boot.